# Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.Web.Helpers.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I have two MVC Websites in my Solution, converted to MVC5. For an specific test, I need both sites running, because one communicates with the other via Web API. They are using IIS Express to run.

When I start one of them inside Visual Studio (2012) and access the started one, everything works fine. When I try to access the other one, I have the following message:

> Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.Web.Helpers.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)' failed.

As suggested by other answers, I updated all my packages and uninstalled `DotNetOpenAuth` packages from one of them, with no result.

This is the `package.config` at site #1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AntiXSS" version="4.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="BeginCollectionItem" version="1.2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Code52.i18n.MVC4" version="0.2.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CSS-Filters-Polyfill" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNet.Highcharts" version="2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Facebook" version="6.4.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Faker" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Faker.Net" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Galleria.js" version="1.2.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ImageResizer" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="iTextSharp" version="4.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Cookie" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.MaskedInput" version="1.3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.10.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.8.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jquery-globalize" version="0.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.13" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.18" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ModelMetadataExtensionsWithBugfix" version="0.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.0.10827" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="morelinq" version="1.0.16006" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MvcMailer" version="4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MvcScaffolding" version="1.0.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="PagedList" version="1.16.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="PagedList.Mvc" version="4.3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RazorGenerator.Mvc" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RazorGenerator.Testing" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RazorPDF" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ReflectionMagic" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="104.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SendGrid" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Management.Automation" version="6.1.7601.17515" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Web.Providers" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="T4Scaffolding" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="T4Scaffolding.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

And `packages.config` at site #2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="BeginCollectionItem" version="1.2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CSS-Filters-Polyfill" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Facebook" version="6.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ImageResizer" version="3.4.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.MaskedInput" version="1.3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.10.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.9.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery-Timepicker-Addon" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.13" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.18" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MvcFlash.Core" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MvcScaffolding" version="1.0.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="T4Scaffolding" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="T4Scaffolding.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="XmlExport" version="0.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="XmlOutput" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

What else I can try?

**EDIT**

Web API Call (one site calls the other site):

```
if (SettingsHelper.GetCurrentSettings().IntegratedToFederated)
{
    // Report Federated
    var pointsGranted = new APIPointsGrantedModel();
    pointsGranted.CustomerId = customerPointsPerShop.Customer.ControlKey;
    pointsGranted.ShopId = (Guid)customerPointsPerShop.Shop.ControlKey;
    pointsGranted.Amount = customerPointsPerShop.Points;
    pointsGranted.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();
    var website = context.Settings.FirstOrDefault().FederatedWebsite;
    Uri theUri = new Uri(website + "/api/APIShops/PointsGranted");
    HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, StringContentHelper.BuildStringContent(pointsGranted, pointsGranted.GetType()));

    if (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await aResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<APIPointsGrantedModel>();
        // Read the response and perform some business logic
    }
    else
    {
        String failureMsg = "HTTP Status: " + aResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + " - Reason: " + aResponse.ReasonPhrase;
        this.FlashError(failureMsg);
        // TODO: Register in log.
    }
}
```

`web.config` at site #1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  ...
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.4.13329" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.4.13329" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.WebData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Moq" publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1402.2112" newVersion="4.2.1402.2112" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="itextsharp" publicKeyToken="8354ae6d2174ddca" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    ...
</configuration>
```

`web.config` at site #2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.WebData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Moq" publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1402.2112" newVersion="4.2.1402.2112" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  ...
 </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please include your Web API call (from client) in your post. Also, please explain: are you making requests across domains in both cases, only in 1, in neither? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not relevant for the answer, but I edited my question to clarify. Both sites send commands, one to the other, because one is the main site of a "federation", and the other is controlled by this main one.

Comment: It may not be relevant. Everytime I see cross domain requests I'm concerned about same origin policy restrictions. So, I wanted to confirm that you enabled CORS

Comment: Sorry, I meant that as a question: Have you enabled CORS on the Web-API provider?

Comment: I'm still developing the code. There's no need to enable this at this time.

Comment: Can you post your web.config?  I had the exact same issue, and it was due to not mapping the proper versions of the new assemblies in the web.config (both global and view folders)

Comment: @Tommy Updated as requested. I had to remove some parts to fit the max chars from the question body.

Comment: Thanks - everything looks good to me, I bounced my packages.config and web.config on the project I had issues with, and everything seemed to match up upon quick glance.  I wish I could remember exactly what the problem was, but it was over a month ago at this point :/  Double check your compilation and httpRuntime elements in the web.config (targetFramework=4.5)

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, this will sound like a horrendous idea, but you may be better off creating a new mvc 5 project and "adding" all files from current project to it...

Comment: @DaveA I did. Additionally, I created a new fresh project with minimal dependencies, and had the same error. I'm suspecting that `machine.config` could be the root of the problem, because I'm having to publish the projects at standard IIS to use the sites simultaneously, but I think this way is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Microsoft-Web-Helpers has been replaced  with Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers. You should remove the old package first,  and then install the newer package.

I opened up the NuGet Package Manager and installed the package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers and things started to work.  Note that when you create a new MVC 5 application and try to incorporate SimpleSecurity or SimpleMembership you will hit the same issue because Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers  is not installed by default.  It has to be present for SimpleMembership to run correctly.

I verified that all of the features in the reference application are working correctly after the upgrade.  Even the generation of the emails using Postal worked, which I was not sure of because of the upgrade of Razor as well.

One change I needed to make to the SimpleSecurity assembly was to remove the filters AuthorizeAttribute and BasicAuthorizeAttribute and put them in a separate assembly.  I did this because they are dependent upon MVC and Web API assemblies.  So now there is a version for MVC  and another for MVC 5.

Refer this link :
http://ctsoftr.com/upgrading-from-asp-net-mvc-4-to-5/

Comment: Note that these steps were done before, as indicated by the `packages.config` I've posted from the both websites. The matter begins when I try to access the two sites at the same time. The one that is in debug works properly, while the other one has the error.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez - and yet the error says Microsoft.Web.Helpers, the package you supposedly have already removed... hmmm.... doesn't that set off a warning bell for you?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Seems like a bug or kind of.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will Suggest to **use Visual Studio 2013 for MVC 5**, if possible.

Seems you have already tried many things, but I am reiterating some of the things(since it can help someone other with the same issue) that must be checked & can be the cause of the issue:

1. Update all nuget packages. (by packages.config seems you have done it)
2. In `global.asax`, change:

   `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);`

   To

   `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`
3. Remove any of the following ASP.NET NuGet packages that are installed using below commands in package manager:

   ```
   Uninstall-Package -Id Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Administration

   Uninstall-Package -Id Microsoft-Web-Helpers

   Uninstall-Package -Id Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes
   ```

   (seems you have done that too).
4. In the web.config make sure these changes are there:

In `<runtime>/<assemblyBinding>` section, and  make the sure correct `newVersion` is there:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <!--Two elements removed for Clarity -->
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <!--WebGrease element removed for Clarity -->
  </assemblyBinding>
```

`5`. Locate the `<appSettings>` section in web.config and update the  **webpages:version from 2.0.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.0** as shown below:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

`6`. Remove any trust levels other than Full like:

```
<securityPolicy>
   <!--<trustLevel name="Medium"  policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config"/>-->
</securityPolicy>
```

7.**Update the web.config files under the Views folder**

- Update all elements that contain `System.Web.Mvc` from version “**4.0.0.0**”  to  version“**5.0.0.0**”.

  `

  ```
  -->
      <pages
          validateRequest="false"
          pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
          pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
          userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <controls>
              <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
          </controls>
      </pages>
  </system.web>`
  ```
- Update all elements that contain `System.Web.WebPages.Razor`  from  version “**2.0.0.0**”  to  version“**3.0.0.0**”. If this section contains `System.Web.WebPages`,  update those elements from  version “**2.0.0.0**” to  version“**3.0.0.0**”

  ```
  <configuration>
      <configSections>
          <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
              <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
              <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
          </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>`
  ```
- If you removed the Microsoft-Web-Helpers NuGet package in a  previous step, install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers`  with  the following command in the PMC:

  ```
  Install-Package -Id  Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
  ```
- If your app uses the  `User.IsInRole()` method, add the following to the `Web.config` file.

  ```
  <system.webServer>
      <modules>
          <remove name="RoleManager" />
      </modules>
  </system.webServer>`
  ```
- **Remove the MVC 4 project type GUID from the project files.**

  - In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and then select Unload Project.
  - Right-click the project and select Edit `ProjectName.csproj`.
  - Locate the `ProjectTypeGuids` element and then remove  the MVC 4 project GUID, `{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}`.
  - Save and close the open project file.
  - Right-click the project and select Reload Project.

  Hope it will help.

Source: [www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I made all your steps (the project was migrated from MVC4 to MVC5) in both projects and apparently the problem is not in the dependencies or in the configuration. It seems something related with the default `machine.config` entries.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message, it had something to do with a package that was changed but not properly updated everywhere (don't know why, don't know how, you can imagine the joy this error brought).. I threw away my packages folder and rebuilt the project et voila... only hours later and I'm back to coding

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete official migrating guide:

[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

The main changes include:

- The Medium Trust is not longer available (the Full Trust should be now used);
- The packages compatible with MVC 5 and Web API 2 should be used now.